# WSG84 to WebMercator: missing raster data along ±180°

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, mapbox

I've converted a GeoTIFF in WGS 84 (EPSG 4326) into mbtiles format (EPSG 3857) and uploaded this to Mapbox. However in Mapbox it renders with a white strip at ±180°. I realise that this is an artifact of the transform between the two coordinate systems, however I'm struggling to work out how to correct it. Obviously the image wraps around to meet itself, but the conversion commands don't seem to account for this. (I’m assuming the error stems from the GDAL commands I’ve used, not Mapbox itself)

Here’s what it looks like (you can see it online at https://xrain.info/data if you change the background to “mean annual depth”):

[image: White strip at ±180°]

These are the commands that I've used so far:

```
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:3857 -tr 2444 2444 -r near -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co ZLEVEL=9 "Mean annual depth (Arctic).tif" mean_ann_depth_arctic_3857_z6.tif
gdal_translate -of MBTILES -co TILE_FORMAT=PNG -co ZLEVEL=9 -co ZOOM_LEVEL_STRATEGY=LOWER mean_ann_depth_arctic_3857_z6.tif mean_ann_depth_arctic_z6.mbtiles
gdaladdo mean_ann_depth_arctic_z6.mbtiles
```

Here's the gdalinfo for my input file ("Mean annual depth (Arctic).tif"):

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: Mean annual depth (Arctic).tif
Size is 3600, 1800
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (-180.000000000000000,90.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (0.100000000000000,-0.100000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=DEFLATE
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-180.0000000,  90.0000000) (180d 0' 0.00"W, 90d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Left  (-180.0000000, -90.0000000) (180d 0' 0.00"W, 90d 0' 0.00"S)
Upper Right ( 180.0000000,  90.0000000) (180d 0' 0.00"E, 90d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Right ( 180.0000000, -90.0000000) (180d 0' 0.00"E, 90d 0' 0.00"S)
Center      (   0.0000000,   0.0000000) (  0d 0' 0.01"E,  0d 0' 0.01"N)
Band 1 Block=3600x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Band 2 Block=3600x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Band 3 Block=3600x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Band 4 Block=3600x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction for fixing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked out that my [antimeridian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/180th_meridian) problem was to do with the pixel size that I had specified: that resolution didn't quite give me the right extent. The solution was to define the extent and the number of pixels and let gdal calculate the pixel size itself:

```
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:3857 -te -20037508.34 -20037508.34 20037508.34 20037508.34 -ts 16384 16384 -r near -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co ZLEVEL=9 "Mean annual depth (Arctic).tif" mean_ann_depth_arctic_3857_z6.tif
gdal_translate -of MBTILES -co TILE_FORMAT=PNG -co ZLEVEL=9 -co ZOOM_LEVEL_STRATEGY=LOWER mean_ann_depth_arctic_3857_z6.tif mean_ann_depth_arctic_z6.mbtiles
gdaladdo mean_ann_depth_arctic_z6.mbtiles
```